# How can I turn this from swift to objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm following a tutorial but it is in swift and the project I'm working on it's partially written in Objective-C. I already "translated" half of the code but I can't change this part yet.

```
// Constrain the top of the button bar to the bottom of the segmented control
buttonBar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: segmentedControl.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
buttonBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 5).isActive = true
// Constrain the button bar to the left side of the segmented control
buttonBar.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: segmentedControl.leftAnchor).isActive = true
// Constrain the button bar to the width of the segmented control divided by the number of segments
buttonBar.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: segmentedControl.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1 / CGFloat(segmentedControl.numberOfSegments)).isActive = true
```

I already have this, but I don't know how to put the `.isActive` part.

```
[buttonBar.topAnchor constraintEqual:_segmentedControl.bottomAnchor];
```

How can I do it?

Comment: You mean `[buttonBar.topAnchor constraintEqual:_segmentedControl.bottomAnchor].active = YES;` ?

Comment: In both Swift and Objective-C, you really should use `NSLayoutConstraint.activate`/`NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints` instead of several separate uses of `isActive/active`.

Comment: Just to expand on what rmaddy said ^^, `activateConstraints` according to the docs is similar to setting `active` to `YES` for each constraint in an array, but is "typically" more efficient. IOW, if you just have one constraint to activate, it's fine to set it's `active` property directly; if you have a bunch (as in the question), stick 'em in an array and use `activateConstraints` instead.

Comment: Yes but for example how can I multiply in the last line? `buttonBar.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: segmentedControl.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1 / CGFloat(segmentedControl.numberOfSegments)).isActive = true`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do

```
[buttonBar.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:_segmentedControl.bottomAnchor].active = YES;
```

Apple docs usually a good place to start:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslayoutanchor?language=objc

In response to your comment about multipliers again read the docs. For example scrolling down on that we see:

> **Note:**
>
> You never use the NSLayoutAnchor class directly. Instead, use one of its subclasses, based on the type of constraint you wish to create.
>   - Use NSLayoutXAxisAnchor to create horizontal constraints.
>   - Use NSLayoutYAxisAnchor to create vertical constraints.
>   - Use NSLayoutDimension to create constraints that affect the view’s height or width.

So width and height constraints are actually `NSLayoutDimension` and those have [extra methods](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslayoutdimension?language=objc), specifically: `constraintEqualToAnchor:multiplier:`

Even if you don't want to reference the docs every time, auto-complete is your friend. Just start typing something like `[self.widthAnchor constraint` and see what comes up

Comment: It says `No visible @interface for 'NSLayoutYAxisAnchor' declares the selector 'constraintEqual:'`

Comment: Ah, yeah I assumed your function was correct, after going to the apple docs I just linked, it turns out it should be `constraintEqualToAnchor` :). Edited my answer

Comment: What about the last line? where I need to multiply

Comment: I'm sorry, my xcode was bugged and it was showing me errors that did't existed

Comment: np, just trying to help to make you better at finding this info on your own. Xcode is notoriously broken so lol relatable. if its clearly wrong usually a good thing to try is a build (`CMD + B`) or a clean (`Shift + CMD + K`) both are under the Product dropdown at the top and there should be a progress loader along the very top for reference

Answer (score 2):

> I don't know how to put the .isActive part.

Each of the lines you cite does several things. For example:

```
buttonBar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: segmentedControl.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

You have to understand what's going on here in order to be able to convert it to a different language. Let's break it down from left to right:

```
buttonBar
```

This is a variable that points to a view of some sort, presumably a `UIToolbar`, but it doesn't really matter as long as it's a view.

```
.topAnchor
```

You're calling the `topAnchor` accessor method, which will return an `NSLayoutAnchor` object (in fact, a `NSLayoutYAxisAnchor` object). Objective-C has similar dot syntax for accessors, so you could say `buttonBar.topAnchor` there too, but you can also write it as `[buttonBar topAnchor]`, which might help you see what's going on.

```
.constraint(equalTo: ________)
```

This is a call to the `constraint(equalTo:)` method. Objective-C's dot syntax doesn't work when there are parameters involved, so you need the messaging syntax. If you're not sure how to translate the name, just look up the Swift name and then change the docs to show Objective-C: `constraintEqualToAnchor:`. So this part translates to `[_____ constraintEqualToAnchor:_____]`.

```
segmentedControl.bottomAnchor
```

This is the same as above: you're just getting the `bottomAnchor` property of `segmentedControl`. The result is used as the parameter to the `constraintEqualToAnchor:` method. Let's put what we've got so far together:

```
[[buttonBar topAnchor] constraintEqualTo:[segmentedControl bottomAnchor]]
```

In other words, you're telling the button bar's top anchor to create a constraint that will make it equal to the segment control's bottom anchor. That constraint is returned by the `constraintEqualTo:` method, which brings us to the last part:

```
.isActive = true
```

Here you're setting the `isActive` property of the constraint returned by `constraintEqualTo:`. So, in Objective-C, you've got:

```
[[[buttonBar topAnchor] constraintEqualTo:[segmentedControl bottomAnchor]] setActive:YES];
```

Or, using Obj-C's dot syntax:

```
[buttonBar.topAnchor constraintEqualTo:segmentedControl.bottomAnchor].active = YES;
```

> Yes but for example how can I multiply in the last line?

That last line is:

```
buttonBar.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: segmentedControl.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1 / CGFloat(segmentedControl.numberOfSegments)).isActive = true
```

If you followed all of the above, then you can probably see that you're really doing the same thing, just calling a different method to get the constraint. That method is `constraint(equalTo:multiplier:)` in Swift, or `constraintEqualToAnchor:multiplier:` in Objective-C. So do the same thing...

```
[_____ constraintEqualToAnchor:_____ multiplier:_____].active = YES;
```

Now just fill in the blanks:

```
[buttonBar.widthAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:segmentedControl.widthAnchor
          multiplier:1/CGFloat(segmentedControl.numberOfSegments)].active = YES;
```